# how can i choose a specific activity and grind index using appium?

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm using appium to automated an already installed app on my device.

(i didn't write it, and it's not my apk).

after a starting splash activity, comes the main activity with a photo grid view.

How can i know what is the name of that activity? I'm using an app from google play called "apk info". which tells all the activities names.

But how can I know what is the name of this specific activity?

```
androidCapabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "???");
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a separate question for #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plug your android device to PC, open the logs, click on the app from device(open it), in the logs you will get the package name and activity name if you have logs enabled.

Comment: `adb shell` with waht params?